# how to set status code using dispatcher result type in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ServletDispatcherResult.html

The above links says that `dispatcher` result type, takes only 2 params `location` & `parse`, but I need to set the httpStatusCode of the response being sent.

I have also gone through http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/result-types.html and http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/httpheader-result.html

but then `httpheader` doesn't take `location`. The goal is to have features of both, any idea on how it can be done ?

The actual requirement is :

If the URL invocation is ajax, I need to return 401 and if that's hit directly, I have to show "Unauthorized Access" message. So, if somehow I can return a JSP along with status-code, then it'll do the job.

Comment: You can always create your own result type. Out of curiosity why do you want this?

Comment: @AleksandrM if the URL invocation is ajax, I need to return 401 and if that's hit directly, I have to show "Unauthorized Access" message. So, if somehow I can return a JSP along with status-code, then it'll do the job.

Comment: So you want to check this in the result? Better do this in interceptor.

Comment: Can you help with some code please, on how such an interceptor with a status code will look like.

Comment: Create an interceptor where you check whether this is ajax or not and return different results.

Comment: @AleksandrM thanks that worked. If you can post this as answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of logic is better to implement in interceptor not in the result. Create custom interceptor that checks whether current request is AJAX or not and return different results from it.